# Android: Problems with a Toolbar at the bottom of the screen

Tags: android, android-menu, android-toolbar

I am using the newest `AppCompat` library and replaced the `SupportActionBar` with a `Toolbar`, as suggested by the Android developer's blog. I want to display a second `Toolbar` at the bottom of the screen, that shows an additional `Menu` from some xml menu resource, but nothing else.

I have two problems with that:

1. Although nothing but a `Menu` is displayed (using `Toolbar.inflateMenu()`), the Menu occupies only a small space on the right side of the toolbar.
2. The `Overflow Action Menu` expands to the bottom of the toolbar and is therefore not shown. It should expand to the top.

Here is a screenshot of the bottom `Toolbar`:

[image: Bottom toolbar screenshot]

How can I solve those issues without being forced to create custom views for my Buttons?

Comment: At what point exactly are you inflating the menu to the bottom toolbar? An action menu is always shown on the right side, just like in the ActionBar, so that's what it's supposed to look like. However, the overflow menu should expand to the top, it is for me. I currently have the problem though that `onOptionsItemSelected` is not called for the buttons at the bottom.. are the buttons at least working for you?

Comment: I know that the ActionMenu should be shown on the right side, however, I would expect that the available space is used to show additional buttons. There seems to be some fixed width limit though. I am not sure anymore, where I inflated the xml, because I solved the issue by writing my own view.

Comment: Ok.. I'm assuming you added `app:showAsAction="always"` to your xml menu items?

Comment: I think it was ifRoom, which should also be displayed when there is room.

Comment: Yes but who knows if the remaining space is calculated correctly. I just tested with "always" and it works. (Could fix my button problem as well, had to set a separate `setOnMenuItemClickListener` on the bottom toolbar)

Comment: With using `always`, one loses all the flexibility which was the reason one used the `ActionMenuView` in the first place. I.e., showing different amounts of icons depending on screen orientation and/or screen width. Hence, one could as well go with a custom view instead of a toolbar.

Comment: That's true, I'm just surprised by the behaviour your experienced, because for me either `ifRoom` and `always` work properly as expected. Even if I have a custom view on the left taking up quite some space, action buttons are still shown when there is room. I assumed you set the option to `never`.

Comment: Are you using the AppCompat library or the native Toolbar?

Comment: AppCompat, latest release.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your comments. I'll try using the bottom Toolbar sometime again and, if the issue persists, it'll be best to provide a sample project.